# How to use /std:c++latest with Qt 5.12

Tags: qt, qmake, visual-studio-2019, c++20, qt5.12

Prior to Qt 5.12, we had `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /std:c++latest` in our `.pri` file but after Qt 5.12 both `c++latest` *and* `c++14` are being set as visual studio command line parameters in the generated `.vcxproj` project file.

I can get to C++17 via `config += c++17`, but then I get this error: `Command line warning D9025: overriding '/std:c++latest' with '/std:c++17'`.

How do I use the latest C++ standard in Visual Studio 2019 when using project files created by qmake?  <s>Said another way, how can I keep qmake from automatically inserting its own `-std` option?</s>

Edit: I was wrong about c++14 automatically being applied.  Another .pri file had set it.

Comment: Looks like something you might want to report in the Qt bug tracker.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75653

Answer (score 4):

In Qt 5.13 you can work around the issue by adding

```
CONFIG += c++2a c++1z c++14
```

to your .pro file. The c++2a value maps to /std:c++latest.

Comment: For me, this only produced `-std:c++17` in the .vcxproj.  (using QMake version 3.1 from Qt version 5.12.3 in `.../Qt5.12.3/5.12.3/msvc2017/lib`)

Comment: Ah sorry, c++2a maps to /std:c++latest. And that was added in 5.13. Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this in your *.pro* file:

```
CONFIG += c++latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONFIG -= c++14` in the .pri (.pro) file in addition to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /std:c++latest` to keep qmake from inserting its own `/std` compile flag.

Edit: this is only needed if a previously included .pri has `CONFIG -= c++14` (and you cannot remove that from the other .pri)